# Digital signature between Java and Delphi

Tags: java, delphi, rsa

I'm working on a project where I need to implement digital signature between Java and Delphi. I'm developing the Java part and another developer the Delphi part.

We were able to interop signing with the private key using SHA256WithRSA (base 64 from the signed bytes is the same).

I'm using OpenJDK implementation and the Delphi dev is using the Chilkat library.

The problem is with the signature verification. We were not able to get the same byte representation of the public key on the two languages.

Java base 64 representation of the public key

```
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA2L6O8YUP5vNJAjqIZAh8yMaPdL+Xcs2lwI9+bvstQT+3sy8S/EC15BoL7vIbp7I2SarPp9ASvxTRvU6sNyD5cVPUW05NkBOM24uhdLs8TNXibbnQAVAMpjkMGkmqZTTeWfYjeHImwjX/K32mNSC+F3i2rQHLtnyPO2ktmAW9lJbGvdwAX0HT0CBT9Z4tZKVn3cRlJva2bqK5z/0xx8Po+Yzh2eK1WZC3coKQQggiPVzFcJJFHtICuklrFZ+vTkpx3apFov27XgkWhCjh6ZZ7UPIVHEZhTlixKBxM36agRZTqZROwFc01nau9f4HWCpsnbm2RBoT3IkNxEq8IRgcFaQIDAQAB
```

Delphi base 64 representation of the public key

```
MD8BIjANBgkqP0g/9w0BAQEFAAM/AQ8AMD8BCgI/AQEA2L4/8T8P5vNJAjo/ZAh8yMaPdL8/cs2lwI9+bvstQT+3sy8S/EC15BoL7vIbp7I2SarPp9ASvxTRvU6sNyD5cVPUW05NkBM/2z+hdLs8TNXibbnQAVAMpjkMGkmqZTTeWfYjeHImwjX/K32mNSC+F3i2rQHLtnyPO2ktPwW9Pz/GvdwAX0HT0CBT9T8tZKVn3cRlJva2bqK5z/0xx8Po+T/h2eK1WZC3cj+QQggiPVzFcD9FHtICuklrFT+vTkpx3apFov27XgkWPyjh6T97UPIVHEZhTlixKBxM36agRT/qZROwFc01nau9f4HWCj8nbm0/Bj/3IkNxEq8IRgcFaQIDAQAB
```

The difference is small, but enough to make the key not work on the other language.

Any ideias?

Thanks

Comment: Not without the code, no.

Comment: Answer to be found in your code. Good luck. [mcve].

Comment: The base64 output is different because the input data that being encoded is different.  If you decode the two base64 strings into raw bytes, you will see that the two sets of bytes have differences between them.  Your two codes are not producing the same bytes prior to base64 encoding.

Comment: If you have the Chilkat software, do they supply their Java version with it? If so, you could check if there's any difference (which is huge, by the way, not small) doing the same thing between their Java version and their Windows DLL for Delphi. As the others say, without seeing the code differences (which could also make a difference), it's impossible to even make a start on what might be wrong.

Comment: This is debugging 101. Trace the execution and intermediate values of both programs and find the point where they diverge. It's disappointing that the modern programmer seems not to have learnt these skills.

Comment: I didn't posted the code because my initial idea was to get some feedback of someone familiar with the Chilkat lib. 

Using their Java version was my last option since Java already has a good implementation of encryption.

I ended up trying it and figured out how to get the same value for the public key. I'll add it as a answer.

Debugging would be obvious if the Chilkat code was available, so please spare me of comments like "It's disappointing that the modern programmer seems not to have learnt these skills."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the same value from *java.security.PublicKey.getEnconded()* on Chilkat library you have to use *CkPublicKey.GetDer()* and pass **false** to the boolean parameter to make it use the PKCS8 format.